# Text Shadow Effect with CSS3

Tags: html, css

i have the following designed with CSS:

[image]

And I love the way the text sort of sinks into the background, like a depression.  Now I tried replicating the same effect using CSS for some other colours:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see it doesn't look as it should like in the first image, the text does not have the same depression or 'sunk in' look as the first image. I tried playing around with the CSS text-shadow effect but i could not get these three to look like the first.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get an inset shadow inside of text with CSS. You'd need to use an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some fairly simple CSS for 'inset' shadow -

```css
.inset {
    color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    text-shadow: rgb(175, 175, 175) -1px -1px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inset">Inset Shadow</div>
```

You will have to play with the settings to tweak them for your use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/) for text shadow generation. It is quite compatible with all the major browsers.